# How to output serial numbers with function call?

Tags: java

here is my code for class `IpdurationAccess` how to put serial numbers with function call?

```
public class IpDurationAccess {
String clientAddress;
int duration;

public IpDurationAccess(String s,int b)
{
    this.clientAddress=s;
    this.duration=b;
}

public String getClientAddress() {
    return clientAddress;
}
public void setClientAddress(String clientAddress) {
    this.clientAddress = clientAddress;
}
public int getDuration() {
    return duration;
}
public void setDuration(int duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}

public void displayContent()
{
    System.out.print( clientAddress+"\t");
    System.out.print(duration);
    System.out.println();

}
}
```

Have return this code I wish to output IP address,duration along with serial numbers. How can I do with `displaycontent()` method?

```
      Iterator iterator;
      System.out.println("IP Address \t Bytes Used ");  
        iterator = logarray.iterator();  
        int count = 1;
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            IpDurationAccess item= (IpDurationAccess)iterator.next();

            item.displayContent();
        }
```

Comment: show the class `IpDurationAccess`

Comment: what is in `logarray` and what is `IpDurationAccess` ?

Comment: where to paste next code??i am not getting option here

Comment: @user3168935 Just edit the question.

Comment: logarray is a ArrayList